# jQuery expander plugin css text display fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why does the text line up in a different line when its displayed?
[image: pic]

jquery plugin:http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

HTML:

```
<div class="expandable">
        <span style="font-size:13px;">Description this is an item that is very good and i like it very cool muchtion this is an item that is very good and i like it very much Descr this is an item that is very good and i like it very much Desc this is an item that is very good and i like it very much pt</span>
        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('div.expandable span').expander({
slicePoint:       69,  // default is 100

expandText:       'More', // default is 'read more'

userCollapseText: 'Less'  // default is 'read less'
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a div has per defualt set the following css rule:

```
display: block;
```

That means, that it fills a hole new line, unless you don´t change it to:

```
display: inline;
```

In conclusion, please try to set it to an inline element.

Furthermore, I don´t think that you need the surrounding div. A span element is per default always inline. Just set the class from the div there, change your jQuery selector and everything should work fine.

Edit: For more information about the css display property please look here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Edit: The plugin sets the for some strange reason the display property while execution of expanding/collapsing. So, what you need to do is to change the

```
$('div.expandable span').expander({
slicePoint:       69,  // default is 100

expandText:       'More', // default is 'read more'

userCollapseText: 'Less'  // default is 'read less'
});
```

call to

```
$('div.expandable span').expander({
slicePoint:       69,  // default is 100
afterExpand: function()
             {
                $("div.expandable span").css("display", "inline");
             },
expandText:       'More', // default is 'read more'

userCollapseText: 'Less'  // default is 'read less'
});
```

Sometimes, the default handling of jQuery .show() method not also does the excepted. Sometimes you would need to define your own show method on an element. And I think the plugin just uses .show(), which causes the display error.

Comment: then some properties are set to the class before. Please give us an full example of what doesnt work.

Comment: plugin auto set display inline block!

Comment: sorry, I didn´t look at the plugin.

Comment: Hey how do overwrite the plugins css